# how do you add a new column with data into a datagrid which already displays data?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a WPF application to display the distance between two postcodes and then I want that distance to be displayed in a new column on the datagrids. I was wondering which is the best way to go about doing this?
here is the code I have which loads the Datagrid with the already populated database

```
        void LoadDataGrid(string command, DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, connect);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        connect.Close();
        dataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        dataGrid.DataContext = dt;
    }
```

and also, here is the code for actually loading it into the datagrid

```
            if (GPSurgeryBox.IsChecked == true)
           {
            LoadDataGrid("select distinct nameOfService as Surgeries, street, city, postcode, 
            contactNumber from gpSurgery", DataGridGP);
           }
```

here is the code I'm using to extract the postcodes from the database

```
        private List<string> GetPostcodes(string table)
    {
        connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();
        string selectString = "select postcode from " + table;
        List<string> postcodes = new List<string>();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectString,connect);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            postcodes.Add(reader.GetOrdinal("postcode").ToString());
        }
        connect.Close();

        return postcodes;
    }
```

and also here is my XAML code

```
    <Grid Margin="0,10,0,-10">
    <TextBox x:Name="PostcodeBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="219,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" />
    <CheckBox Name="GPSurgeryBox" Content="GP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
    <CheckBox Name="DentistBox" Content="Dentist" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox Name="SchoolsBox" Content="Schools" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.533,-5.633"/>
    <CheckBox Name="OpticianBox" Content="Opticians" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="445,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.421,-3.6"/>
    <CheckBox Name="NurseryBox" Content="Nursery" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.344,3.2"/>
    <Button  x:Name="SearchButton" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="293,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="SearchButton_Click"/>
    <RadioButton  x:Name="MilesButton"  Content="Miles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="MilesButton_Checked"/>
    <RadioButton  x:Name="KMButton"  Content="Kilometers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="364,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="KMButton_Checked"/>
    <Label Content="Enter A Postcode:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="0,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792">
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridGP" Height="63" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridDentist" Height="63" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridSchools" Height="63" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridNursery" Height="63" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridOpticians" Height="63" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Add a new column to the `DataTable`?

Comment: will adding `datatable.Columns.Add("distance", typeof(string))` solve it?

Comment: Yes, it should give you a new column.

Comment: I added it into my `LoadDataGrid` method but there was no column added when it was ran

Comment: Did you add the column to `dt`? The `DataGrid` should show all columns that are in the `DataTable` that you set as its `DataContext`.

Comment: `dt.Columns.Add("Distance", typeof(string));` that is the line which i added into the method

Comment: Do you get an empty column or no column at all?

Comment: No column at all

Comment: And you are not defining the columns explicitly somewhere else in your code?

Comment: The only time the column is defined is in that method, The only other columns which are used are the ones which are displayed directly from MySql

Comment: @mm8 the column is now displaying, I don't know why it wasn't working, to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new column to your `DataTable` in your `LoadDataGrid` method:

```
void LoadDataGrid(string command, DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    ...
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    ...
    dt.Columns.Add("Distance", typeof(string));
    dataGrid.DataContext = dt;
}
```